# Bash script to delete occasional chars and eols

Tags: bash

My data file is supposed to be in rows delimited by 400 tabs with an end of line at the end. Unfortunately some random eols have appeared on many rows.

I'd be grateful for tips on how to process the file to remove the random eols (but leave the 'real' eol at the end of each line.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think you should be a bit more specific; "delimited by 400 tabs" makes it sound as if there's supposed to be 400 tab:s between each column, which I think is not what you mean. 400 tab-delimited columns per line, and some lines are shorter by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like tr to do what you want, for example:

```
[root@C1100-05 dmc]# echo -e "\na\nbcd"

a
bcd
[root@C1100-05 dmc]# echo -e "\na\nbcd" | tr -d '\n'
abcd[root@C1100-05 dmc]#
```

then all you will need to do is add in the \n at the end of your line so it has the EOL at the correct spot

Comment: This deletes the final newline.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep to do this, but you have to go through some work to get the TAB character into it. What I did just now was creating a pattern file that looked like this:

```
\([^    ]*      \)\{3,\}
```

where those big white spaces are actual tabs (I used emacs and did a (what-cursor-position) to make sure).

This particular pattern looks for 3 or more fields where a "field" is "zero or more non-tab chars followed by a tab delimiter". You actually want the bad lines, so reverse that grep:

```
grep -vf <patternfile> <datafile>
```

Now iterate over those lines and apply a `tr -d '\n'` to each. Echo the result with a *new* newline and you are done. (I'd put this altogether in a script but I'm time-limited and I don't know what your file looks like anyway.)

Comment: You can get a tab with `^v<TAB>` (ctrl+v, tab key)

Comment: Yeah, I read that while trying this. It didn't work for me, though.